# select default channel race condition

Tags: go

https://play.golang.org/p/FMKxtVlTL5

Why does the `default:` in the select statement infinite loop the program?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var quit chan bool
var counter chan int

func main() {
    counter = make(chan int)
    quit = make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        i := 0
        for {
            i++
            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("Bye!")
                return
            case counter <- i:
                fmt.Println("Send! " + strconv.Itoa(i))
            default:
                fmt.Println("Default! " + strconv.Itoa(i))
            }
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    fmt.Println("Receive! " + strconv.Itoa(<-counter))
    quit <- true
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, but you don't need to explicitly convert integers to strings in order to print them: `fmt.Println("Receive!",<-counter)` or `fmt.Printf("Receive! %d\n", <-counter)` would work just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `select` has a `default`, it becomes non-blocking. To quote the spec:

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.

Without the `default`, the `select` would wait until it could receive from `quit` or send on `counter`, do that, and then continue (going through the `for` loop again, unless it ran that `return`). *With* the default, the `select` never waits for anything and the `default` simply runs every time it can, unless one of the other operations goes through.

In theory the program still works the same, and will exit after the sixth time of printing "Send!" and "Receive!" — but it might be too busy printing "Default!" several billion times to get there in a reasonable time.

Comment: Yep. @Gert, add `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` to `default:` and see how the program behaves.

Comment: Thanks :D PS Can you add @Nadh suggestion to your answer please https://play.golang.org/p/YWAg9tTUqU

Comment: @GertCuykens it's not a great suggestion — sleeping would mean spending a bunch of time doing nothing, ignoring messages that *are* available, and slowing the program down. The real solution is not to have a default if you don't need it, and not to do something silly like printing in it if you do :)

Comment: True, but it does illustrate the problem very well :)

Comment: @hobbs The suggestion is of course not a solution! Just a way to illustrate what happens.